# Problems with Python in QGIS 2.14 on UBUNTU 14.04

Tags: qgis, ubuntu, plugins

So far, I have not been able to install correctly QGIS on Ubuntu 14.04. I have tried with different versions of QGIS, different repositories, different tutorials, but I have always had the same issue about Python:

> Couldn't load plugin 'processing'
>
> AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'GRIORA_NearestNeighbour' 
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/qgis/utils.py", line 281, in loadPlugin
>       **import**(packageName)
>     File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/qgis/utils.py", line 572, in _import
>       mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
>     File "/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins/processing/**init**.py", line 29, in 
>       from processing.tools.general import *
>     File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/qgis/utils.py", line 572, in _import
>       mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
>     File "/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins/processing/tools/general.py", line 28, in 
>       from processing.core.Processing import Processing
>     File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/qgis/utils.py", line 572, in _import
>       mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
>     File "/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins/processing/core/Processing.py", line 48, in 
>       from processing.algs.qgis.QGISAlgorithmProvider import QGISAlgorithmProvider
>     File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/qgis/utils.py", line 572, in _import
>       mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
>     File "/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins/processing/algs/qgis/QGISAlgorithmProvider.py", line 107, in 
>       from RasterLayerStatistics import RasterLayerStatistics
>     File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/qgis/utils.py", line 572, in _import
>       mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
>     File "/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins/processing/algs/qgis/RasterLayerStatistics.py", line 36, in 
>       from processing.tools import raster
>     File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/qgis/utils.py", line 572, in _import
>       mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
>     File "/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins/processing/tools/raster.py", line 30, in 
>       from osgeo import gdal
>     File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/qgis/utils.py", line 572, in _import
>       mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/osgeo/gdal.py", line 83, in 
>       from gdalconst import *
>     File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/qgis/utils.py", line 572, in _import
>       mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/osgeo/gdalconst.py", line 86, in 
>       GRIORA_NearestNeighbour = _gdalconst.GRIORA_NearestNeighbour
>   AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'GRIORA_NearestNeighbour'
>
> Python version: 2.7.6 (default, Oct 26 2016, 20:33:43) [GCC 4.8.4] 
>   QGIS version: 2.14.3-Essen Essen, exported
>
> Python Path:
>   /usr/share/qgis/python
>   /home/jos/.qgis2/python
>   /home/jos/.qgis2/python/plugins
>   /usr/share/qgis/python/plugins
>   /usr/lib/python2.7
>   /usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu
>   /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk
>   /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old
>   /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload
>   /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
>   /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
>   /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PILcompat
>   /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gst-0.10
>   /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0
>   /usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7
>   /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntu-sso-client
>   /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/wx-2.8-gtk2-unicode
>   /home/jos/.qgis2//python
>   /usr/share/qgis/python/plugins/fTools/tools

For these reasons I can't use the plugins of QGIS.

Any ideas on how to resolve this issue?

Comment: this error occurs when you open qgis? if so did you tried to manual install the processing module with `pip install processing` ?

Comment: I have just installed the processing module you told me but I have the same error: when I open qgis I have the warning I included in the first message.

Comment: You are using a very old version of QGIS. The LTR version is now 2.14.14. Maybe the issue has been fixed in the meantime. Installing processing with pip is not necessary (beiing a core plugin now), and might bring other problems. I think you have mixed versions in /usr/local/lib/ and /usr/lib/.

Comment: Thank all of you for replying. I have uploaded to version 2.14.14 and now I have two messages when I open QGIS:


> Couldn't load plugin 'processing' 

> AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'wkbCircularString' 

> blablablablablabla


And the second one:
> Couldn't load plugin GdalTools due to an error when calling its classFactory() method 

> AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'GRIORA_NearestNeighbour' 

When you say "I think you have mixed versions in /usr/local/lib/ and /usr/lib/", what do you mean? Versions about QGIS? Python?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Mixed versions of GDAL python. It seems you have self-compiled some of it (in /usr/local/lib/) using pip, which does not work with downloaded packages (in /usr/lib/). I suggest to remove the local stuff, and remove, purge and autoclean all packages, and stick to one repo.

Comment: No solution. Two messages:

"Couldn't load plugin 'processing' 

ImportError: libgdal.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory" 

"Unable to load GdalTools plugin. 
The required "osgeo [python-gdal]" module is missing. 
Install it and try again."

Is there another way to install QGIS 2.14 on UBUNTU 14.04? Snap? A tutorial or web page? I always have problems with gdal and python libraries.

Comment: Still mixed versions on your side I suppose. You can have package `python-gdal` v 1.10 from the main ubuntu repo, or v2.1.0 from the ubuntugis stable PPA. Both work for me (in separate virtual boxes). Perhaps you should try a clean install in a virtual box. Or update your OS to xenial to make a fresh install.

Comment: I will try with virtualbox. Could you recommend me a tutorial/webpage where I can install correctly QGIS with Gdal-library? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I follow the steps from the QGIS download page (with **OR** without ubuntugis), and it works for me including GDAL out of the box.

Comment: Ok. I have installed QGIS some times from the offical download page and I do not have problems to install that software. The problem happens when I install the GDAL library. I have to compile it in order to open the ortophotos. I will try it another time! Thanks.